Is it possible to detect the card type (Credit/Debit) using Clover API or Clover Android SDK?
I'm working on an integration using the Clover API and/or the Clover Android SDK, and I need to identify whether a card is a credit or debit card during a transaction. Is there a way to programmatically detect the card type (Credit or Debit) through either of these tools?
I've explored the Clover API documentation and the Android SDK but couldn't find specific information on detecting the card type directly. Any insights on how to achieve this or any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
I want to know, what does the PAN, Track (1, 2, 3) response are? From this API: https://docs.clover.com/dev/reference/read_card
Thanks in advance!
